# Configuration of fluent-plugin-concat makes the logs dissappear

Tags: docker, logging, amazon-ecs, fluentd, fluent-docker

my configuration of ” fluent-plugin-concat” is causing my long logs to disappear instead of be concatenated and sent to Kinesis steam.
I use fluentd to send logs from containers deployed on AWS/ECS to a kinesis stream. ( and then to ES cluster somewhere)
on rare occasions, some of the logs are very big. most of the time they are under the docker limit of 16K. However, those rare long logs are very important and we don't want to miss them.

My configuration file is attached.

Just before the final match sequence, I added:

```
<filter>
@type concat
key log
stream_identity_key container_id
partial_key partial_message
partial_value true
separator “”
</filter>
```

Another configuration I tried:
with the bellow options only the second partial log is sent too ES, the first part can only be seen in the fluentd logs. Adding the logs of this config as a file.

```
<filter>
  @type concat
  key log
  stream_identity_key partial_id
  use_partial_metadata true
  separator ""
</filter>
 

and 


<filter>
  @type concat
  key log
  use_partial_metadata true
  separator ""
</filter>
```

The log I’m testing with is also attached as a json document.
If I removed this configuration, this log will be sent in 2 chunks.
What am I doing wrong? (edited)

the full config file:

```
<system>
  log_level info
</system>

# just listen on the unix socket in a dir mounted from host
# input is a json object, with the actual log line in the `log` field
<source>
  @type unix
  path /var/fluentd/fluentd.sock
</source>

# tag log line as json or text
<match service.*.*>
  @type rewrite_tag_filter
  <rule>
    key log
    pattern /.*"logType":\s*"application"/
    tag application.${tag}.json
  </rule>
  <rule>
    key log
    pattern /.*"logType":\s*"exception"/
    tag exception.${tag}.json
  </rule>
  <rule>
    key log
    pattern /.*"logType":\s*"audit"/
    tag audit.${tag}.json
  </rule>
  <rule>
    key log
    pattern /^\{".*\}$/
    tag default.${tag}.json
  </rule>
  <rule>
    key log
    pattern /.+/
    tag default.${tag}.txt
  </rule>
</match>

<filter *.service.*.*.*>
  @type record_transformer
  <record>
    service ${tag_parts[2]}
    childService ${tag_parts[3]}
  </record>
</filter>

<filter *.service.*.*.json>
  @type parser
  key_name log
  reserve_data true
  remove_key_name_field true
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse>
</filter>

<filter *.service.*.*.*>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby
  <record>
    @timestamp ${ require 'time'; Time.now.utc.iso8601(3) }
  </record>
</filter>


<filter>
  @type concat
  key log
  stream_identity_key container_id
  partial_key partial_message
  partial_value true
  separator ""
</filter>

<match exception.service.*.*.*>
  @type copy
  <store>
    @type kinesis_streams
    region "#{ENV['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION']}"
    stream_name the-name-ex
    debug false

    <instance_profile_credentials>
    </instance_profile_credentials>

    <buffer>
      flush_at_shutdown true
      flush_interval 10
      chunk_limit_size 16m
      flush_thread_interval 1.0
      flush_thread_burst_interval 1.0
      flush_thread_count 1
    </buffer>
  </store>

  <store>
    @type stdout
  </store>
 </match>

<match audit.service.*.*.json>
  @type copy

  <store>
    @type kinesis_streams
    region "#{ENV['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION']}"
    stream_name the-name-sa

    debug false

    <instance_profile_credentials>
    </instance_profile_credentials>

    <buffer>
      flush_at_shutdown true
      flush_interval 1
      chunk_limit_size 16m
      flush_thread_interval 0.1
      flush_thread_burst_interval 0.01
      flush_thread_count 15
    </buffer>
  </store>


  <store>
    @type stdout
  </store>

</match>

<match *.service.*.*.*>
  @type copy
  <store>
    @type kinesis_streams
    region "#{ENV['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION']}"
    stream_name  the-name-apl
    debug false

    <instance_profile_credentials>
    </instance_profile_credentials>

    <buffer>
      flush_at_shutdown true
      flush_interval 10
      chunk_limit_size 16m
      flush_thread_interval 1.0
      flush_thread_burst_interval 1.0
      flush_thread_count 1
    </buffer>
  </store>

  <store>
    @type stdout
  </store>
 </match>



 <match **>
  @type stdout
 </match>
```

example  log message - long single line:

```
{"message": "some message", "longlogtest": "averylongjsonline", "service": "longlog-service", "logType": "application", "log": "aaa .... ( ~18000 chars )..longlogThisIsTheEndOfTheLongLog"}
```

fluentd-container-log ... contains only the first part of the message:
and the following error message:

dump an error event: error_class=Fluent::Plugin::Parser::ParserError error="pattern not match with data

```
2021-03-05 13:45:41.886672929 +0000 fluent.warn: {"error":"#<Fluent::Plugin::Parser::ParserError: pattern not match with data '{\"message\": \"some message\", \"longlogtest\": \"averylongjsonline\", \"service\": \"longlog-service\", \"logType\": \"application\", \"log\": \"aaaasssssdddddjjjjjjjkkkkkkklllllllwewwwiiiiiilonglogaaaasssssdddddjjjjjjjkkkkkkklllllllwewwwiiiiiilonglogaaaasssssdddddjjjjjjjkkkkkkklllllllwewww
< .....Manay lines of original log erased here......  > 
djjjjjjjkkkkkkklllllllwewwwiiiaaaasssssdddddjjjjjjjkkkkkkklllllllwewwwiiiiiilongloglonglogaaaassss'>","location":null,"tag":"application.service.longlog.none.json","time":1614951941,"record":{"source":"stdout","log":"{\"message\": \"some message\", \"longlogtest\": \"averylongjsonline\", \"service\": \"longlog-service\", \"logType\": \"application\", \"log\": \"aaaasssssdddddjjjjjjjkkkkkkklllllllwewwwiiiiiilonglogaaaasssssdddddjjjjjjjkkkkkkklllllllwewwwiiiiiilonglogaaaasssssdddddjjjjjjjkkkkkkklllllllwewww
< .....Manay lines of original log erased here......  > 
wwiiiiiilonglogaaaasssssdddddjjjjjjjkkkkkkklllllllwewwwiiiaaaasssssdddddjjjjjjjkkkkkkklllllllwewwwiiiiiilongloglonglogaaaassss","partial_message":"true","partial_id":"5c752c1bbfda586f1b867a8ce2274e0ed0418e8e10d5e8602d9fefdb8ad2b7a1","partial_ordinal":"1","partial_last":"false","container_id":"803c0ebe4e6875ea072ce21179e4ac2d12e947b5649ce343ee243b5c28ad595a","container_name":"/ecs-longlog-18-longlog-b6b5ae85ededf4db1f00","service":"longlog","childService":"none"},"message"
:"dump an error event: error_class=Fluent::Plugin::Parser::ParserError error=\"pattern not match with data '{\\\"message\\\": \\\"some message\\\", \\\"longlogtest\\\": \\\"averylongjsonline\\\", \\\"service\\\": \\\"longlog-service\\\", \\\"logType\\\": \\\"application\\\", \\\"log\\\": \\\"aaaasssssdddddjjjjjjjkkkkkkklllllllwewwwiiiiiilonglogaaaasssssdddddjjjjjjjkkkkkkklllllllwewwwiiiiiilonglogaaaasssssdddddjjjjjjjkkkkkkklllllllwewwwiiiiiilonglogaaaasssssdddddjjjjjjjkkkkkkklllllllwewwwiiiiiilonglogaaaasss
```

Comment: Ideas on how to debug are also welcome ( I have access to the fluentd container)

Comment: I also tried with "stream_identity_key partial_id" instead of "container_id"

Comment: Do you see these logs printed out via `stdout`?

Comment: What is your docker version? Under [Usage](https://github.com/fluent-plugins-nursery/fluent-plugin-concat#usage), there are different configurations for different docker versions. Please verify if you're using the right one according to your docker version.

Comment: Hi Azeem, Docker:    19.03.13-ce.

Comment: I added some more optional configuraiton that I tried and the error message from the fluentd log.

Comment: The parser didn't get the correct value to work with. Did you try to run with debug flags? For example: `fluentd -vv ...`. You are using `log_level`. You can set that to `debug` and then run this.

Comment: Also, you can just isolate this parsing issue from the rest of your config. Just comment out the config which is unrelated to this and then run some tests.